# custom View Cell in listview having only button clickable

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I want to create a viewcell which stacklayout containing Frame for border each row. This Frame contains labels and one button. On this button click I have to change screen.

I find an issue when I render that code on iOS simulator and found out that on selection of any rows i.e. viewcell, it grays out and show blurred selected row which looks ugly. I tried to disable the view cell which solved my row selection issue but it also disabled button click on row as it is part of it.

I only requires a button to be enabled and available for click and rest of the part on viewcell should not be clickable or available to select. I have to use frame for border purpose. Which also provides rounded border but suggest me some solution which I can use in place of frame for borders as well.

Screenshot:
[image]

```
<ListView x:Name="lstView" RowHeight="150" SeparatorVisibility="None" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="False" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <StackLayout Padding="10,10,10,10">
          <Frame OutlineColor="Silver">
            <Grid>
              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
              </Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <Label Text="Car Type" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
              <Label Text="{Binding CreatedDate}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
              <Label Text="{Binding TransactionId}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
              <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="Status" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Status}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
              </StackLayout>
              <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="Customer Name" />
                <Label Text="{Binding CustName}" />
              </StackLayout>
              <Button Text="Button" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Clicked="OnClicked" CommandParameter="{Binding DisplayName}"></Button>
            </Grid>
          </Frame>
          </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

Comment: You can remove the background color of listview item on selection.By rendering the ViewCell and setting `SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None`

Comment: This is in xamarin forms. Is there any way I can do it on xamarin forms. or Please help me in writing code in rendreer.  My target is to use as much cross platform as I can as I am targeting android and windows phone as well.

Comment: also, akash, Can I only configure SelectionStyle property at of Cell at iOS end and rest I can do at Xamarin Forms Xaml end like design ViewCell as I have done above?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Selection
If you want to disable selection, handle the ItemSelected event and set the SelectedItem property to null:

```
SelectionDemoList.ItemSelected += (sender, e) => {
((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
```

};

Source:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity/

Answer (score 0):

Same effect was happening with me on Ios side in xamarin forms it is due to frame. 
comment frame tag axml code your code will work normal listview this effect will gone

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and follow the guideline there to provide quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, if you wanna stick to xamarin forms only, is to the ViewCell BackgroundColor or the Layout in your ViewCell.View to white.

So in this case:

```
<DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <StackLayout Padding="10,10,10,10" BackgroundColor="White">
```

But because of the padding, there might be some space left transparent, showing the touch response when hitting the ViewCell